# A generic error occurred in GDI+ selenium webdriver

Tags: c#-4.0, selenium, webdriver

I get  generic error occurred in GDI+ for selenium webdriver.It was working fine still yesterday,But suddenly I get this error.

```
   public string TakeScreenshot(IWebDriver driver, string SnapFolderPath, string TCID, string KeyFunction)
    {
        try
        {
            //  driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            ITakesScreenshot ssdriver = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
            Screenshot screenshot = ssdriver.GetScreenshot();
            string filePath = testReport + "\\" + TCID + "_" + KeyFunction + "_" + GetDateTimeforFilePath() + ".png";
            screenshot.SaveAsFile(filePath, ImageFormat.Png);

            return filePath;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: External Exception:.{"A generic error occurred in GDI+."}

Comment: I see you've solved it, but just for further reference this doesn't come from Selenium, this comes from the GDI library. (Selenium just calls some .NET code from Microsoft to save the screenshot)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Resolved this Issue .We need to give full access permission to the folder where we want to store the image.If we don't give full permission we get this error

Comment: Another potential problem, I was giving it a directory name that did not exist and it doesn't auto-create it.  You need to create the directory first.

Comment: I had a similar issue that two selenium drivers were each writing an image to the same file (i.e. with the same filename).